# CakePHP translations in one or multiple po files and performance

Tags: performance, cakephp, internationalization, po

Does making the i18n tool of CakePHP making its po file in single one file better than multiple files. Here I meant by performance. Personally, I prefer single one file I regarded it easier to translate the application, but I mean the performance of the application on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one file is better than multiple files, due to the performance used when opening and closing multi files is greater than opening one file regarding-less its size.